# Doxygen filter format?

Tags: filter, doxygen

With my team we create software we need to document. I have found doxygen which seems a nice program to do this. Although our programming language is not supported (RAPID).

Yesterday I have asked a question about this. Albert was kind enough to provide a clue in the right direction. A filter should be the right way to go in stead of an preprocessor.

But I did not provide the syntax of the RAPID code which can be found here : 
http://futurecnc.code.arc.cmu.edu/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/RAPID-Reference-Manual-Instructions.pdf

I found the help guide about creating filters from the doxygen website. Also i have found an example filter created by Bert Jordan for perl :
http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html

Some questions :

2. Is a filter the right way to go, or is a preprocessor needed ?
3. What is the filter exactly doing ?
4. Doxygen has an lexical scanner, what kind of format must be used for the filter to convert the rapid code to a supported language?

I hope, I have given a clear description now :)

**edit : I'm searching for information about how to create the actual filter.
Does anybody know a good source for this ?**

Comment: Regarding point 3 and 4: The filter should scan the input file, given as argument to the filter, convert it to a language understood by doxygen and write all out to stdout. Doxygen will pick the result from the "stdout" of the filter.

Comment: Hi @albert, thx again for answering. Cannot seem to find any guide or information on how to actually program the filter, do you know some source ?

Comment: I don't know a source for the filter format either. The output of the filter should be a source file (on stdout) that is understood natively by doxygen.

Comment: thx again, but there must be some kind of documentation on how to add a filter ? What do you exactly mean with : "The output of the filter should be a source file (on stdout) " ?

Comment: The, limited, documentation regarding adding the filter is in the Doxyfile (and in the configuration chapter of the manual, chapter 23. The Doxyfile and manual are more or less identical as they are generated from the same source). "The output of the filter should be a source file (on stdout) ", means that the filter should convert the original file to the "new" format and dump this to stdout (so the filter creates in its own memory space an new file and should dump this to stdout. The simplest filter is 'cat' which dumps its input to stdout).

Comment: again thx for answering ! Sorry but what do you mean with : The Doxyfile and manual are more or less identical as they are generated from the same source).

and this : the simplest filter is 'cat' which dumps its input to stdout
what is cat ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some examples on filters for other languages at the doxygen site under [the helpers section](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html).

I have used an doxygen filter (which is not listed there) for Bash for one of my projects. The filter is pretty simple and might be a good example. This filter is available at [Anvils github](https://github.com/Anvil/bash-doxygen).

In essence it is just a ~130 line sed script converting bash to quasi-C which doxygen can parse. You could write your own sed script for RAPID.

You should add it to your Doxyfile with:

```
# Tell doxygen to handle files with sh extension as C files
EXTENSION_MAPPING = sh=C

# Tell doxygen to run sh files through the below sed script
FILTER_PATTERNS        = *.sh=MY_PATH/doxygen-bash.sed
```

There is also a python example via the helpers page [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150627011139/http://home.in.tum.de/%7Egrembowi/vbfilter/vbfilter.py).

The main part to understand is that the filter can be anything you like to write. Python, sed, shell, etc. Doxygen just calls your filter, runs the code through it and your filter should output a language Doxygen can parse.

Comment: Thanks you are my hero of the day ! But i can't find any code examples on the helpers page, am i overlooking something ?

Comment: See my additions, a filter just would take in a RAPID file and outputs a file that contorts it to a C-like file. The filter can be written in any language you like.

Comment: oke thanks for the clarification now i understand it (i think haha). But then it is just a seperated program. is it possible to call the filter program from doxygen when you run it or do you just run it as a seperated program.

Comment: The `FILTER_PATTERNS` tag in your Doxyfile makes doxygen call that program/script when doxygen encounters that extension.

Comment: finally I think I understand it and how to tackle the problem. Just for verification that I understand it : I have to create a program(filter) which is invoked by doxygen when it starts to run. invoking it can be done by altering the settings of the doxyfile. Secondly the filter functions are to convert language syntax (RAPID) to a c code syntax, so the laxilal scanner of doxygen can interpret it and create the html page with the UML charts. is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It is started  each time a file of the specfied type is parsed.

Comment: @pwghost, if this answer solved your problem, then you should click the checkmark on the upper left side of the answer to select it as your Accepted Answer, and click the up arrow to upvote it; user1149326 will surely appreciate this as it will improve his reputation score.

Comment: @sifferman oke i will do that. if i have a follow up question should i post it here ? or make a new question ?

Comment: If it's a small clarification, you can do it in the comments, like we're doing here. If the follow up question has enough significance to stand on its own, then you should start a new question.

Comment: It would be great if you'd add to your answer how exactly a filter works. [Something like this](https://github.com/Hi-Angel/notes-backup/blob/master/doxygen.md#writing-a-plugin). I'd write an answer myself, but for the most part you already answered it. In fact I've used your answer as a starting point *(I upvoted you too)*. However it still costed me some hours of reverse-engineering the sed script. It would be nice to save someone's time in the future by mentioning how exactly a Doxygen filter works, IOW what you want to do inside it to add support for a new lang or an odd construction.