# Doxygen include plain text

Tags: include, doxygen

Is there a way to include plain text in a doxygen file

```
 Hello Wold
 ----------

 @include helloworld.txt
```

without it ending up in a fragment like:

[I dont want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNScM.png)

​I wanted it to end up like the other text I write in a .markdown file:

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI00h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say I don't think there's an easy way to do this as of May 2016 - what you really need is a `mdinclude` command to match [htmlinclude](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdhtmlinclude).

The problem is that Markdown is processed as a pre-processing step and the output from that then run through the normal Doxygen processing detecting generated HTML and special commands.

So, unless you want to make a submission to Doxygen, the only way I can think of is to do your own pre-processing for this particular include.

You could do that in a build step where you use some Unix commands or a script to merge in a file at the include stage.

If you wanted this driven by Doxygen you could use a custom file extension and write your own filter, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174663/doxygen-filter-format)